# AttributeError: __enter__ Speech Recognition

Tags: python, pandas, speech-recognition, spotipy

I am trying to make voice asssistant with python. I got the resources from github. Everything seems right but when I try to run the project it says:

```
File "c:\Users\icell\Desktop\Programlama\Python\python_calışma\jarvis.py", line 45, in <module>
    with m as source:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

I cant recognized that problem.For any advice I will be very very pleased..
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from speech_recognition import Microphone, Recognizer, UnknownValueError
import spotipy as sp
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
from pepper import *


setup = pd.read_csv('setup/setup.txt', sep='=',index_col=0, squeeze=True, header=None)
client_id = setup['client_id']
client_secret = setup['client_secret']
device_name = setup['device_name']
redirect_uri = setup['redirect_uri']
username = setup['username']
scope = setup['scope']

auth_manager = SpotifyOAuth(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret,
    redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
    scope=scope,
    username=username)
spotify = sp.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)


devices = spotify.devices()
deviceID = None
for d in devices['devices']:
    d['name'] = d['name'].replace('’', '\'')
    if d['name'] == device_name:
        deviceID = d['id']
        break
r = Recognizer()
m = None
input_mic = 'Rampage'
for i, microphone_name in enumerate(Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
    if microphone_name == input_mic:
        m = Microphone(device_index=i)

while True:
    with m as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source=source)
        audio = r.listen(source=source)

    command = None
    try:
        command = r.recognize_google(audio_data=audio).lower()
    except UnknownValueError:
        continue

    print(command)
    words = command.split()
    if len(words) <= 1:
        print('Could not understand. Try again')
        continue

    name = ' '.join(words[1:])
    try:
        if words[0] == 'album':
            uri = get_album_uri(spotify=spotify, name=name)
            play_album(spotify=spotify, device_id=deviceID, uri=uri)
        elif words[0] == 'artist':
            uri = get_artist_uri(spotify=spotify, name=name)
            play_artist(spotify=spotify, device_id=deviceID, uri=uri)
        elif words[0] == 'play':
            uri = get_track_uri(spotify=spotify, name=name)
            play_track(spotify=spotify, device_id=deviceID, uri=uri)
        else:
            print('Specify either "album", "artist" or "play". Try Again')
    except InvalidSearchError:
        print('InvalidSearchError. Try Again')
```

Error on this lines:

```
with m as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source=source)
        audio = r.listen(source=source)
```

I am literarly dont know enter atribute. Thats why I dont have any idea for this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m = None`
I change this line to this:
`m= Microphone(device_index=0)`

Comment: Ah, my mistake if my advice wasn't about the real issue, I'm not familiar with the `speech_recognition` module. Great that your problem is solved, though! Remember to set your answer as Accepted to close the thread.

Comment: I will accept. Thank you again for your advice. I am very glad for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

`__enter__` is simply a non mandatory object method that's called when a `with` is called on said object. To be more specific:

> `object.__enter__(self)`:
> Enter the runtime context related to this object. The with statement will bind this method’s return value to the target(s) specified in the as clause of the statement, if any.

From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers.

In your case, that's your `Microphone`, named `m`. Since it has no `__enter__` method, the program can't call it in `with m as source:` and throws an error.

```py
# with m as source: # Unnecessary
r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source=m)
audio = r.listen(source=m)
```

However, you don't need to necessarily call this `with` on `m` for your program to work. You can simply remove this line, replace `source` by `m` in those two lines, and it should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you for your brilliant advice. But I solved this issue like this:```m= Microphone(device_index=0)``` m was none and I think I can change this and it work